# What are the $x$, $y$, and $z$ components of a force acting on $i$-th atom in a Lennard-Jones system of $N$ atoms?

Tags: forces, molecular-dynamics

What are the $x$, $y$, and $z$ components of a force acting on the i-th atom in a Lennard-Jones system of $N$ atoms?

**According to my understanding:**

The Lennard-Jones potential function is given by the equation:
$$V(r) = 4\varepsilon\left[\left(\frac{\sigma}{r}\right)^{12} - \left(\frac{\sigma}{r}\right)^{6}\right],$$
where $V(r)$ is the potential energy between two atoms separated by a distance $r$, $\varepsilon$ is the depth of the potential well, and $\sigma$ is the distance at which the potential is zero.

To obtain the force components along the $x$, $y$, and $z$ axes ($F_{i,x}$, $F_{i,y}$, and $F_{i,z}$), we need to take the negative gradient of the potential function with respect to the corresponding coordinates. Mathematically, the components of the force can be obtained as follows:
$$F_{i,x} = -\frac{\partial V(r_{ij})}{\partial x_{i}} \\
F_{i,y} = -\frac{\partial V(r_{ij})}{\partial y_{i}} \\
F_{i,z} = -\frac{\partial V(r_{ij})}{\partial z_{i}},$$
where $x_{i}$, $y_{i}$, and $z_{i}$ are the coordinates of the $i$-th atom. To calculate these force components, we need to differentiate the Lennard-Jones potential function with respect to the coordinates of the atom.

To expand the term $F_x^i = -\frac{\partial V(r_{ij})}{\partial x_{i}}$, we need to differentiate the Lennard-Jones potential function $V(r_{ij})$ with respect to the $x$-coordinate ($x_{i}$) of the atom.

Let's break down the expansion step by step:

1. Start with the Lennard-Jones potential function:
   $$V(r_{ij}) = 4 \cdot \varepsilon \cdot \left[\left(\frac{\sigma}{r_{ij}}\right)^{12} - \left(\frac{\sigma}{r_{ij}}\right)^{6}\right]$$
2. Differentiate $V(r_{ij})$ with respect to $x_i$:
   $$F_{x}^i = \sum_{i=0}^{N} \sum_{j=0}^{N} \varepsilon \cdot \left[ \sigma_{ij}^{12}  \frac{\partial} {\partial x_{i}} \frac{1}{r_{ij}^{12}} - 2 \sigma_{ij}^{6} \frac{\partial} {\partial x_{i}} \frac{1}{r_{ij}^{6}} \right]$$

here, $$r_{ij} = \sqrt{(x_i - x_j)^2 + (y_i - y_j)^2 + (z_i - z_j)^2}$$
therefore,

$$ \Rightarrow F_{x}^i = \sum_{i=0}^{N} \sum_{j=0}^{N} 12 \cdot \varepsilon \cdot \left[ \frac{ \sigma_{ij}^{6}} {(x_i-x_j)^7} - \frac{ \sigma_{ij}^{12}} {(x_i-x_j)^{13}}  \right]$$

This is a general expression for the $x$-component of the force in a Lennard-Jones system, which depends on the positions of both the $i$-th and $j$-th atoms.

**Is this correct?**

If so, where does the following come from?

[image]

Also, **why is only one summation?**

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4766486/is-this-partial-integration-correct